# Como hacer envio por formulario ajax (agregar al carrito)

Tags: php, ajax, formularios

Estoy creando una pagina web e-commerce, ya esta toda lista, pero note que en el momento de agregar un producto al carrito te redirige al inicio de la seccion productos (osea en el producto 1) en la pc no afecta casi nada ya que los productos entran todos en la pantalla, pero si estas en dispositivo mobil y agregaste 1 producto que esta muy abajo, esto seria muy tedioso, al principio se me ocurrio agregar en el `action` del `form` una redirecion al id del producto y asi evitar ir al inicio, pero pero esta redireccion queda muy raro y hasta puede llegar a marear al cliente. Entonces intente hacerlo con ajax, ya revise otros post y hasta vi tutoriales pero ninguno me sirve.
Lo que quiero es que al presionar Agregar al carrito, se agregue. Les dejo partes del codigo:

productos:

```
<?php include 'ff.php'; ?>
<div class="container">
        <div class="back-container"><button class ="back" onclick="location.href='alhuevo.php'"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left-long"></i></button></div>
            <section class="Productos">
                <article class="fideos-grimaldi">
                        <h1>Cortos</h1>      
                        <div class="productos">
                        <?php
                            $select_products = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE categoria='fgcorto'") or die('query failed');
                            $select_products->execute();
                            $list_products = $select_products->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            foreach($list_products as $producto){
                            include 'productact.php'; } ?>                     
                        </div>
                </article>       
            </section>
        </div>
```

addCart.php (donde se encuentran las sesiones para agregar al carrito):

```
     <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start(); 
  };
  include 'connect.php';
  include 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt( $_POST['id'], COD, KEY))){
                $ID = openssl_decrypt( $_POST['id'], COD, KEY);                        
            }else{ echo '<script> alert("ID incorrecto"); </script>'; exit;
            }
            if($_POST['cantidad']<1){
            $CANTIDAD = 1;
            }else{                          
                $CANTIDAD = $_POST['cantidad'];
            }
            if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
                $producto=array(
                    'ID'=>$ID,
                    'CANTIDAD'=>$CANTIDAD,
                );
                $_SESSION['cart'][0] = $producto;
                echo 
                '<div class="alert-co" id="alert-co">Producto Añadido Exitosamente</div>';        
            }else{
                $idProductos=array_column($_SESSION['cart'],"ID");
                if(in_array($ID, $idProductos)){
                    echo 
                    '<div class="alert-inc" id="alert-inc">El Producto Ya Ha Sido Agregado</div>';
                }else{
                    $producto=array(
                        'ID'=>$ID,
                        'CANTIDAD'=>$CANTIDAD,
                    );
                    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $producto);  
                    echo 
                    '<div class="alert-co" id="alert-co">Producto Añadido Exitosamente</div>';        
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

productact.php (donde estan cosas generales y form para los productos) (el `alert` luego de `success:function()` fue para comprobar si el id llegaba correctamente):

```
<?php 
$id = $producto['id'];
$codigo = $producto['codigo'];
$imagen = "media/productos/$codigo.png";
$nombre = $producto['nombre'];                   
$precio = $producto['precio']; 
$bulto = $producto['bulto']                
?>
<div class="p" id="<?php echo $id?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $imagen; ?>" alt="<?php echo $nombre?>" title="<?php echo $nombre?>">
    <p ><?php echo $nombre; ?></p>
    <form action="backend/addCart.php" class="formadd" id="<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){?>
            <p>(x <?php echo $bulto; ?>)</p>
            <p class="precioo pps">$<?php echo number_format($precio, 0, ',', '.') ?></p>                                    
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($id,COD,KEY);?>">
            <input class="cantidad pps" type="number" min="1" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" placeholder="1">   
            <div class="cc"><button type="submit" name="btnCart" value="Add" class="c pps">Agregar Al carrito</button></div>
            <?php
            } 
            ?>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $('body').on('submit', '.formadd', function(ev){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
      //FUNCION AJAX
      $.ajax({
        type: $(id).attr('method'),
        url: $(id).attr('action'),
        data: $(id).serialize(),

            success: function(data) {
            $('.cartnro').load(' .cartnro'); // Le hace un reload al nro de productos en el carrito(se encuentra en el header).
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('No se pudo agregar al carrito, intente mas tarde');
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es enviar el formulario mediante **Ajax** para evitar el evento de recarga y mostrar un **Alert** con un mensaje al momento de agregar algo, tu función Ajax es incorrecta, por eso no te funciona, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
//DETECTA EL EVENTO SUBMIT DEL FORMULARIO CON CLASE FORMPRODUCT
$('body').on('submit', '.formProduct', function(event){
//GUARDAMOS EL ID DINÁMICO DEL FORMULARIO QUE HIZO SUBMIT
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
      //FUNCION AJAX
      $.ajax({
        //TOMA LOS ATRIBUTOS DEL FORM CON JQUERY
        //OBTENEMOS EL METODO DE ENVIO DEL FORMULARIO
        type: $(id).attr('method'),
        //OBTENEMOS LA RUTA DE ENVIO DEL FORMULARIO
        url: $(id).attr('action'),
        //TODOS LOS CAMPOS CAPTURADOS EN EL FORMULARIO
        data: $(id).serialize(),
        //FUNCION EJECUTADA ANTES DE ENVIAR
        beforeSend: function() {
          alert('espere..');
        },
        //FUNCION EJECUTADA SI EL ENVIO ES CORRECTO
        success: function(data) {
          alert('Producto agregado exitosamente, siga comprando')
        },
        //FUNCION EJECUTADA AL HABER UN ERORR
        error: function() {
          alert('No se pudo agregar al carrito, intente mas tarde');
        }
      });
      ev.preventDefault(); //EVITAMOS EL EVENTO DE RECARGA AL ENVIAR FORMULARIO
```

En tu formulario no necesitas ejecutar una función *onsubmit*, con **jquery** detectamos ese evento. Es muy importante agregarle un **id** para acceder a el mediante **jquery**, un **method**, un **action** y los **name** que identifique los campos en donde se encuentra la información a mandar, ya que con esos capturaras con php los datos enviados.

```html
< div class="p" id="<?php echo $id?>">
  < img src="<?php echo $imagen; ?>" alt="<?php echo $nombre?>" title="<?php echo $nombre?>">
    < p>
      <?php echo $nombre; ?>
      < /p>
        <!--AQUI LOS ATRIBUTOS IMPORTANTES DEL FORMULARIO-->
        < form id="producto" method="post" action="agrega la ruta PHP">
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){?>
          < p> (x
            <?php echo $bulto; ?>)
            < /p>
              < p class="precioo pps"> $
                <?php echo number_format($precio, 0, ',', '.') ?>
                < /p>
                  < input type="hidden" name="id" id="id <?php echo $id ?>" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($id,COD,KEY);?>">
                    < input class="cantidad pps" type="number" min="1" name="cantidad" id="cantidad <?php echo $id ?>" class="cantidad" placeholder="1">
                      < div class="cc">
                        < button type="submit" name="btnCart" value="Add" class="c pps"> Agregar Al carrito
                          < /button>
                            </div>
                            <?php
            } 
            ?>
                              < /form>
                                < / div>
```

Para tu archivo PHP capturamos los datos enviados

```js
//CAPTURAMOS EL PRIMER DATO, DONDE EL NAME ES ID, COMPROBADO POR ISSET
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  switch ($_POST['id']) {
    case 'Add':
      if (is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY))) {
        $ID = openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'], COD, KEY);
      } else {
        echo 'ID CORRECTO';
        exit;
      }
      if ($_POST['cantidad'] < 1) {
        $CANTIDAD = 1;
      } else {
        $CANTIDAD = $_POST['cantidad'];
      }
      if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $producto = array(
          'ID' => $ID,
          'CANTIDAD' => $CANTIDAD,
        );
        $_SESSION['cart'][0] = $producto;
        $mensajeCo = "Producto Añadido Exitosamente";
      } else {
        $idProductos = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], "ID");
        if (in_array($ID, $idProductos)) {
          $mensajeInc = "El Producto Ya Ha Sido Agregado";
        } else {
          $producto = array(
            'ID' => $ID,
            'CANTIDAD' => $CANTIDAD,
          );
          array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $producto);
          $mensajeCo = "Producto Añadido Exitosamente";
        }
      }
      break;
```

En este archivo **PHP donde recojes los datos**, ordenalos, no le entendí casi nada, indenta tu código y hazlo con scripts separados, los mensajes los puedes imprimir con **echo** solamente, y en ajax los procesas en un alert.Dime si te funciono

Comment: hola buenas, estoy probando el codigo pero como podria hacer para que ajax obtenga este id `<form action="backend/addCart.php" id="formadd<?php echo $id?>" method="post">`. Por que el problema es que si mi `id` seria solamente `formadd` , en el momento de agregar un producto al carrito solo se agrega 1 (el primero que detecte con ese `id`)

Comment: Simplemente cambia el nombre, yo le puse **producto** cambialo por **formadd**

Comment: sisi lo se pero el form tiene un foreach arriba por lo tanto si le pongo simplemente formadd solo 1 producto obtendría ese id, por eso quería saber como ponerle formadd y que tenga la variable id de php, así cada producto tiene por ejemplo "formadd53" y otro "formadd51"

Comment: Agregale a tus form una clase, mediante la clase obtenemos el id:

Comment: He modificado el AJax, donde a los formularios agrégales la misma clase a todos **formProduct** u otra pero que sea la misma clase a todos, con la función detectamos el **submit** del formulario por clase y obtenemos de ese el _id_, almacenamos el id y lo pasamos a los parametros de AJax, espero  con esto se resuelva.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar ahi modifique `addCart.php` y `productact.php` para que veas lo que hice

Comment: Cual es el error?, que ocurre?, no puedo adivinar... Inspecciona la página en tu navegador y ve a consola, ahí suele mostrar los errores, busca e investiga, no podemos resolver todo aquí si no das la información necesaria.

Comment: en la consola no me tira ningun error , lo que pasa es que si me ejecuta la accion de             `success: function(data)` , pero los productos no se añaden al carrito, es decir que lo que no se ejecuta es el lo que esta en el `method`, y ya lo verifique y esta todo bien (o eso creo)

Comment: Verifica con **console.log(nombre-variable)**, el data del success para ver que te devuelve en consola, lo mismo para el id y observa si realmente lo esta haciendo correctamente, con esto compruebas donde esta el error, recuerda que la petición Ajax solo puede interpretar data de php con **echo**, o en formato Json, verifica esos puntos, si realmente envía algo, que envía?...

Comment: Si lo intente y cuando pongo `console.log(id)`, la consola me devuelve el id del producto (osea esto esta bien), el problema es queno se ejectua la accion que esta en `addCart.php`

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo el ajax quedo asi por si alguien lo necesita:

```
$('.formadd').on('submit', function(ev) {   
    var id2 = $(this);   
    $.ajax({
        type: $(id2).attr('method'),
        url: $(id2).attr('action'),
        data: $(id2).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {               
        $('.cantidad').val('');
        $('.cartbasket').load(' .cartbasket');
        $('.alert-co').removeClass('hide')
        },
        error: function() {
        $('.alert-inc').removeClass('hide')
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```